# Google Service Account "Invalid JWT Signature"

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, webdna

I am attempting to write some code in webDNA to connect to the google drive api.  Using the service account seems to be the best solution for the given problem.  From what I have read the process is... create the JWT, send the JWT to google to get a token response, then send the taken response to call api methods.I believe my issue is with the private key.

I build and encrypt the header:

```
[text]header={"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"}[/text]
[text]header=[encrypt method=Base64][header][/encrypt][/text]
[text]header=[db_base64URL varName=header][/text][!]custom function to deal with special characters[/!]
```

Next build and encrypt the claim(added white space for readability):

```
[text]claim={
"iss":"xxx",
"scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
"aud":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
"exp":[Math][cTime]+3600[/Math],
"iat":[cTime]
}[/text]
[text]claim=[encrypt method=Base64][claim][/encrypt][/text]
[text]claim=[db_base64URL varName=claim][/text]
```

Those sections seem to be correct, now to build the signature:

```
[text]p_key=-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----xxxx-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n[/text]
[text]sig=[encrypt method=SHA256][header].[claim].[p_key][/encrypt][/text]
[text]sig=[encrypt method=Base64][sig][/encrypt][/text]
[text]sig=[db_base64URL varName=sig][/text]
```

I have tried moving the [p_key] around, outside the sha256 encryption and inside, with and without the '.', I don't get an error till I try to send it to google using [TCPConnect] and [TCPSend] here:

```
[text show=T]response=[!]
[/!][TCPconnect host=accounts.google.com&SSL=T&port=443][!]
[/!][TCPsend skipheader=T]POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1[crlf][!]
[/!]Host: accounts.google.com[crlf][!]
[/!]Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded[crlf][!]
[/!]Content-Length: [countchars][sendData][/countChars][crlf][!]
[/!]Connection: close[crlf][!]
[/!][crlf][!]
[/!][sendData][crlf][!]
[/!][/TCPsend][!]
[/!][/TCPconnect][/text]
```

When the response is shown it is displayed as:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Invalid JWT Signature."
}
```

This error message is less that helpful, from what I have read it could mean one(or more) of any number of things and google's documentation on this is not exactly helpful.  If anyone has any experience using the google apis through webDNA I would appreciate any help you could give!